# Send email with images using JHipster and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jhipster

I'm trying to use images in my JHipster project, but Thymeleaf can't identify the location of the images in my JHipster project.

My images are located in this folder: *C:\PATH\src\main\webapp\content\img_email* and my HTML templates in: *C:\PATH\src\main\resources\mails*.

I tried following combinations such as *src="../../content/img_email/logo-5asec.jpg"* and even tried to use the notation *th:src="@{~/PATH/img_email/logo-5asec.jpg}"*. I even tried to change the images folder location without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use full URLs for your images (e.g.http://my.domain.org/content/images/something.png) in e-mail messages otherwise a mail client has no idea where to download them from.